# Is it possible to have all skills in the skills tree?

Tags: path-of-exile

I was wondering if it's possible to have all skills in the skills tree or I'm limited with a maximum skill points?

Could be awesome to have a character that can be a god.

Comment: I haven't played the game yet, but are the skills you gain limited by your level? If yes, what's the max level?

Comment: All skills as in every node filled?  Or all skills as in all the major ability nodes, like Minion Instability and Hex Master?

Comment: If you  could do that, PoE char development/building wouldn't be that "open", cause everybody would eventually have the same skill build at end-game, HAH!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum level within the game is 100, allowing for a maximum of 111 passive points to place into your passive tree. Each of these "upgrades" is referred to as a node.

If you are referring to skill gems, these have a maximum level of 20, and have differing level and stat requirements to use.

Comment: With act 3, the max is now 116 I believe.  The official skill tree is not updated though.

Comment: There would be more than 116 if it wasnt updated though

Comment: The current max is 120. 99 from leveling to 100, and 21 from quests. 2 points in act 1, 2 in act 2 (although you go back to act 1 for one of em), and 3 in act 3, times 3 for 3 difficulties.

Comment: Updating as of 2.1.0 in January 2016: max is 123 with one skillpoint reward in act 4 times 3 difficulties.